# 'DatetimeIndex' object has no attribute 'Date'

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I try to Generate Monthly KPIs DataFrame by aggregating Revenue but i got this error :

> AttributeError: 'DatetimeIndex' object has no attribute
> 'Year_Lease_Start'

Here is the format of the dataframe :

```
VEHICLE_TYPE    MARQUE  COMPANY_TYPE    COMPANY_NAME    COMPANY_CODE    PERSONAL    SALESCHANNEL_SUB_CODE   COMP_SEG_SUB_CODE   BELONGS_UNDER_HIERARCHY_CODE    DESCRIPTION CREATED_BY  DATE_CREATED    ACCESS_SET  LEASE_ID    TERM    DISTANCE    LEASE_START LEASE_END   LEASE_EXTENDED_TO   STATUS  QUOTE_ID    QUOTE_REVISION  TITLE_NAME  LOYER_FINANCIER_HT  LOYER_FINANCIER_TTC PRESTATION_HT   PRESTATION_TTC  PRIX    LOYER_TOTAL_HT  Year_Lease_Start    Month_Lease_Start   YearMonth_Lease_Start
Date                                                                                                                                
2018-09-05  NI  rgrgCUS lhkv erge   506183  Y   DIRECT  EPE 002053679_HR    YHE 179868.0    2019-01-23 13:27:39.0   AG_PRime    385590  36  45000   2018-09-05  2021-09-04 00:00:00.0   NaN ACTIVE  3269111 1   Adooper 217.42  260.904 42.57   51.084  35500.0 259.99  2018    9   20180
```

Any idea please to fix this problem? thanks

```
%pylab inline
import warnings
warnings.filterwarnings('ignore')
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
sns.set(style="white", color_codes=True)

# Transforming Lease_start_Date column to datetime type and mapping to a new columne as ILease_start_Date
DIRECT_PART_df.LEASE_START= pd.to_datetime(DIRECT_PART_df.LEASE_START)

# Construct Year, Month and YearMonth from Lease Start Date field
DIRECT_PART_df['Year_Lease_Start'], DIRECT_PART_df['Month_Lease_Start'] = DIRECT_PART_df['LEASE_START'].dt.year, DIRECT_PART_df['LEASE_START'].dt.month
DIRECT_PART_df['YearMonth_Lease_Start'] = DIRECT_PART_df['LEASE_START'].map(lambda x: 100*x.year + x.month)


# Create "Date" column in datetime format to use for index
DIRECT_PART_df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(DIRECT_PART_df.LEASE_START.dt.date)
DIRECT_PART_df.set_index('Date', inplace=True)

# 1. Revenue - Generate Monthly KPIs DataFrame by aggregating Revenue
m_kpis = pd.DataFrame(DIRECT_PART_df.groupby([DIRECT_PART_df.index.Year_Lease_Start, DIRECT_PART_df.index.Year_Lease_Start.Month_Lease_Start])['LOYER_TOTAL_HT'].sum())
```

Comment: without looking at the data it will be difficult to comment anything. Please post data as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is in last row, for columns names use strings, not `DIRECT_PART_df.index.Year_Lease_Start`:

```
m_kpis = DIRECT_PART_df.groupby(['Year_Lease_Start', 'Month_Lease_Start'], as_index=False)['LOYER_TOTAL_HT'].sum()
```

If need also pass index:

```
m_kpis = DIRECT_PART_df.groupby([DIRECT_PART_df.index.year.rename('Year'), DIRECT_PART_df.index.month.rename('Month'), as_index=False)['LOYER_TOTAL_HT'].sum()
```

Comment: thank you it works, but when i try to set Year AND MONTH as index it does not work   `# Rename index to capture Year and Month
m_kpis.index.set_names(['Year', 'Month'], inplace = True)`

Comment: @jjezrael , you means like this ? : `m_kpis = DIRECT_PART_df.groupby([DIRECT_PART_df.index.year.rename('Year'), DIRECT_PART_df.index.month.rename('Month')], as_index=False)['LOYER_TOTAL_HT'].sum()`

Comment: @butter - exactly.

Comment: i have to change it to `as_index=True` to get 2 indexes